# "From the past" or "From my past"?

Tags: word-in-context

"From the past" or "From my past"... which one would be more appropriate to use in the phrase below:

> My weekend's soccer games from the past have now turned into nothing
>   but a reminder of how easy and happy life used to be.

or

> The weekend's soccer games from my past have now turned into nothing
>   but a reminder of how easy and happy life used to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**The past**" means *previous times*.
"**My past**" means your previous life.

Both phrases seem alright for usage in the sentence. You can choose whatever phrase you want, according to the meaning you would like to deliver.
Though personally, I'd prefer the second one, as it seems more accurate (The soccer games from your previous life).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for you answer and considerations. After posting the question I read both phrases and I was afraid that both of them were completely wrong, I mean, that they made no sense at all. Thanks again.